# Converting a string to an integer Java

Tags: java

I am looking to convert the string to an integer so that I can ask the user for input and then count down accordingly.

### Code:

```
String bottle = "bottles";
String num = "";
request.getParameter(bottles);
int number = bottles;
```

Comment: `Integer.parseInt(mystring);`

Comment: I am expecting it to count down for example it starts with 5 bottles then goes down to 4 and continously repeat downwards until 0 bottles.
So it'll be like, 
5 bottles
4 bottles
3 bottles

Answer (score 2):

I would use `Integer.parseInt` and enclose in a `try` / `catch` for a `NumberFormatException` (input `String` does not represent an integer).

I'd also add a null check in case you have no control over the `String` you're parsing.

```
// null check
if (bottles != null) {
    try {
        int foo = Integer.parseInt(bottles);
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        // bottles does not represent an integer
        nfe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Integer.valueOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29) like so,

```
String bottles = request.getParameter("bottles"); // Get the parameter as a String

int number = Integer.valueOf(bottles); // Returns Integer type, and un-boxes.
```

or, you can use [Integer.parseInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) like so,

```
int number = Integer.parseInt(bottles); // Returns primitive type.
```

Both of the options to get the int value may throw a `NumberFormatException`, so you need a to either add that to the `throws` signature of your method or use a `try` `catch` block.

Comment: Ok thanks;
So it should look like this : 
String bottle = "bottles";
String num = "";
String bottles = request.getParameter("bottles"); 
int number = Integer.valueOf(bottles);

Comment: Why define `String bottle = "bottles";`, you aren't using it. Why define `String num = "";` you aren't using that either. Other then that, yes.