# Java - How to divide String by a number?

Tags: java, settext

**New**

```
BigDecimal i = BigDecimal.ZERO;
for (int row = 0; row < testMark.length; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < testMark[row].length; col++) {
        i.add(new BigDecimal(testMark[row][col]));
    }
}
i.divide(new BigDecimal(60D));
outPut.setText(i.toString());`
```

**OLD**

Look at the bottom of the code. I want to divide the whole classAver string by 60 like outPut.setText(classAver/60);

The Array `double[][] testMark = new double[15][4];`

```
String classAver = "";
        for(int i=0; i < rowNumber; i++){
            classAver += ((testMark[0][0] + testMark[0][1] + testMark[0][2] + testMark[0][3])
                   +
                   (testMark[1][0] + testMark[1][1] + testMark[1][2] + testMark[1][3]) +
                   (testMark[2][0] + testMark[2][1] + testMark[2][2] + testMark[2][3]) +
                   (testMark[3][0] + testMark[3][1] + testMark[3][2] + testMark[3][3]) +
                   (testMark[4][0] + testMark[4][1] + testMark[4][2] + testMark[4][3]) +
                   (testMark[5][0] + testMark[5][1] + testMark[5][2] + testMark[5][3]) +
                   (testMark[6][0] + testMark[6][1] + testMark[6][2] + testMark[6][3]) +
                   (testMark[7][0] + testMark[7][1] + testMark[7][2] + testMark[7][3]) +
                   (testMark[8][0] + testMark[8][1] + testMark[8][2] + testMark[8][3]) +
                   (testMark[9][0] + testMark[9][1] + testMark[9][2] + testMark[9][3]) +
                   (testMark[10][0] + testMark[10][1] + testMark[10][2] + testMark[10][3]) +
                   (testMark[11][0] + testMark[11][1] + testMark[11][2] + testMark[11][3]) +
                   (testMark[12][0] + testMark[12][1] + testMark[12][2] + testMark[12][3]) +
                   (testMark[13][0] + testMark[13][1] + testMark[13][2] + testMark[13][3]) +
                   (testMark[14][0] + testMark[14][1] + testMark[14][2] + testMark[14][3]));
        }
outPut.setText(classAver); // <--How do I divide that number by 60?
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting a string to an integer Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22099081/converting-a-string-to-an-integer-java) of course ... using String in the first place is a bad idea.

Comment: What is in your `testMark` array?

Comment: @Conor Watt - Dude you need to refactor your code O.O

Comment: Did you know that you could have used a couple of loops to eliminate those `60` variables being typed.

Comment: Don't use a String variable to hold a numner. Use an int / double. Once you have your final number, and only at this time, then transform it to a string to put it in your text field.

Comment: Why is all that in a `for` loop where you never reference `i` inside the loop?

Comment: Somebody has said that `classAver` isn't really a string because of a different post you made and then deleted.  If that `String classAver` at the top isn't really part of your code, please fix your question.

Comment: Your update is missing the assignment `i = i.add(..)` and `i = i.divide(...)`.

Answer (score 5):

## Edit

Seeing as you specified the array was a `double[15][4]`, you can use this:

```
BigDecimal i = BigDecimal.ZERO;
for (int row = 0; row < testMark.length; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < testMark[row].length; col++) {
        i = i.add(new BigDecimal(testMark[row][col]));
    }
}
i = i.divide(new BigDecimal(60D));
outPut.setText(i.toString());
```

Later down the road, if you want to have an average with more than just 60 results:

```
BigDecimal i = BigDecimal.ZERO;
int count = 0;
for (int row = 0; row < testMark.length; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < testMark[row].length; col++, count++) {
        i = i.add(new BigDecimal(testMark[row][col]));
    }
}
i = i.divide(new BigDecimal(count));
outPut.setText(i.toString());
```

## Old answer

Lordy, where to begin.

For one, loops:

```
for (int row = 0; row < 15; row++) { // these don't need to be concrete numbers ("15"), can be your array length
    for (int col = 0; col < 4; col++) {
        //append testMark[row][col]
    }
}
```

Secondly, use a `StringBuilder`, don't append strings in a loop

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int row = 0; row < 15; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < 4; col++) {
        sb.append(testMark[row][col]); //can append delimiters, etc
    }
}
String value = sb.toString(); //Your complete value
```

Then, cast your value:

```
BigInteger i = BigInteger.valueOf(classAver); //returns an int value
i = i.divide(new BigInteger(60));
outPut.setText(i.toString());
```

If you don't want to add the values as strings, you can add them up as numbers:

```
BigInteger i = BigInteger.ZERO;
for (int row = 0; row < 15; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < 4; col++) {
        try {
            int raw = Integer.parseInt(testMark[row][col]);
            i = i.add(new BigInteger(raw));
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            System.err.println(String.format("Bad value caught! (Row: %d, Col: %d)", row, col));
        }
    }
}
i = i.divide(new BigInteger(60));
outPut.setText(i.toString());
```

Comment: @ajb You are correct, I don't use it often haha. Updating my answer

Comment: `testMark[row].length` is interesting syntax. I had to check it to be sure :). I would prefer `col.length` to be less confusing to a reviewer.

Comment: @staticx It's valid, using `col` would require assigning an extra variable ;)

Comment: @Rogue: It's cheap to be explicit, it's expensive to have brevity :) Good work

Comment: @Rogue: `new BigDecimal(0)` is fine too, you can drop the `D`. Actually you can use `BigDecimal.ZERO`.

Comment: It says cannot find symbol method parseInt(double)

Comment: @ConorWatt Take note of the update at the top. Your change in the provided information changed the answer.

Comment: Sorry, you need to re-assign `i`... `i = i.divide(new BigDecimal(60D));` and `i = i.add(new BigInteger(raw));`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch All assignments fixed

Comment: Im getting 0 as the output

Comment: @ConorWatt Update your OP with the current code you are using?

Comment: @ConorWatt: Original Post.

Comment: @ConorWatt I have updated my post since then, I just tested it and it worked with my current implementation :)

Answer (score 2):

Based on your update, I think you want something like this -

```
double[][] testMark = new double[15][4];
double total = 0; // start at 0.
double count = 0; // keep count.
for (int i = 0; i < testMark.length; i++) {
    // iterate the inner array.
    for (double d : testMark[i]) {
        total += d; // add it to the total.
        count++;    // add one to the count.
    }
}
String classAver = String.valueOf(total / count); // take average (as a String).
outPut.setText(classAver); // Set the text.
```

Answer (score 0):

`classAver` will not hold the value you think it will.  When you write

```
 for(int i=0; i < rowNumber; i++){
     classAver += [some long calculation that really needs to be done with loops];
 }
```

it is equivalent to

```
 for(int i=0; i < rowNumber; i++){
     classAver = classAver + ...; 
 }
```

When you use `+` on a `String`, the program will convert whatever non-`String` operands to `String`, and **concatenate** the strings.  So if you have 5 rows and your calculations produce 1001, 2001, 3001, 4001, and 5001, the resulting `classAver` will not be `"15005"`, but will instead be `"10012001300140015001"`.  (P.S. Now that I know it's a `double`, that makes things a little worse, because you could end up with a garbled string like `"1001.02001.03001.04001.05001.0"`.)

Moral: When you're doing calculations, use numeric types (`int`, `long`, `double`, `BigInteger`, etc.).  Don't use `String`.  After you've finished with the calculation, if you need a `String`, **then** convert it, for example:

```
double classAver;

[compute classAver] 

outPut.setText(Double.toString(classAver));  // or Integer.toString(n) for integers
```

or

```
outPut.setText("" + classAver);
```

Comment: I don't think `classAver` is a `String`. He says it is, but in a deleted post he said it was somethign else

Comment: OP finally disclosed that his numbers are `double`

Comment: @staticx Yes it is.  It's toward the top of his original code snippet.

Comment: @ajb: "but in a deleted post he said it was somethign else". We were trying to help him use `Integer.valueOf` but it takes a `String` and he said it wasn't a `String`. This OP needs to figure out what he wants.

Comment: @staticx your edit and my response crossed in the mail ... anyway, if he's not posting the actual code causing the problem, he needs to fix it.

Comment: I agree, also it's a double now.